# Can I make a powershell that turns on and off the AlwaysOn property in the App service with help of WebJobs? Or is there better ways to schedule it?

Tags: azure, properties, alwayson

Can I make a powershell that turns on/off the AlwaysOn property in the App service with help of WebJobs? Or is there better ways to schedule it?

Comment: Ok, so you're not bound to PowerShell?

Comment: There are REST API's for this, the Azure Management SDK provides the capability.  I've done it in C# using the SDK but haven't used the PowerShell ones.  How you implement it is up to you, there are numerous ways to achieve it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-7.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below azure powershell command **Set-AzWebApp** to turn on and off the **AlwaysOn** property in the App service.

```
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name "ContosoWebApp" -AlwaysOn $true
```

This cmd will Modify an Azure Web App and Ensure that web app gets loaded all the time, rather unloaded after been idle.

```
Type: Boolean
Position: Named
Default value: None
Accept pipeline input: False
Accept wildcard characters: False
```